# Is Planet Nowhere based on a real-world series?

Tags: the-middle

In the TV show, The Middle, Brick Heck is obsessed with a sci-fi book series called Planet Nowhere.

Is there a real-world analogue that show writers used as a base to develop the book series?

Answer (score 3):

The book is featured on [List of fictional books from non-print media](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_books_from_non-print_media) under [Miscellaneous from television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_books_from_non-print_media#Miscellaneous_from_television) so I would say that there is no real-world analogue to it.

Note that the list is pretty big so featuring a fake/fictional book in a TV show or a movie is nothing unusual.